# How to compare instances of a phantom type with respect to the phantom type argument?

Tags: haskell, phantom-types

I have a phantom type:

```
newtype MyType a = {getSth :: SthType}
```

How can I compare `MyType a1` and `MyType a2` with respect to the result of `a1` and `a2` comparison, i.e. if `a1 < a2` then `MyType a1` < `MyType a2`?

Comment: Your `newtype` isn't syntactically correct. That being said, `a1 < a2` indicates that a) both are of the same type and b) both are values, not types, as long as we're talking about `(<) :: Ord a => a -> a -> Bool`. What do you actually want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since comparison using the standard `Eq` and `Ord` type-classes require that both values being compared have the exact same type (including the phantom type parameter) you need to either define your own comparison operators or use an existential wrapper. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

newtype MyType a = MyType { getInt :: Int }

data SomeType = forall a . SomeType (MyType a)

instance Eq SomeType where
  (SomeType (MyType a)) == (SomeType (MyType b)) = a == b

instance Ord SomeType where
  compare (SomeType (MyType a)) (SomeType (MyType b)) = compare a b

test = SomeType a < SomeType b where
  a :: MyType Char
  a = MyType 10

  b :: MyType Float
  b = MyType 15
```

Another option is to use `Data.Coerce` which allows you to use the standard comparison functions without writing any boilerplate instances. You just need to supply some explicit type signatures:

```
import Data.Coerce

test2 :: Bool
test2 = coerce ((<) :: Int -> Int -> Bool) a b where
  a :: MyType Char
  a = MyType 10

  b :: MyType Float
  b = MyType 15
```

Comment: Actually, this doesn't answers original question. The initial goal is to compare somehow `x :: MyType a` with `y :: MyType b` by types `a` and `b` first and only then by values `getInt x` and `getInt y`. You just implemented comparison by values of objects of different types. But you comparison is not lexicographical with respect to types.